# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).carousel Carousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

In my react app, my script for carousel is throwing an error that its is not a function and I am pretty sure that I am messing up with the order of scripts but I can't figure out where.

I have installed jquery as a module, so to avoid collisions I haven't included any jquery CDN, but it seems that script collision is happening anyway.

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.8/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.8/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <title>BandBazaar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cb257d2cdc.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my script

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {


    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 4;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});


  $('#carouselExample').carousel({ 
                interval: 2000
        });


  $(document).ready(function() {
/* show lightbox when clicking a thumbnail */
    $('a.thumb').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var content = $('.modal-body');
      content.empty();
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        $('.modal-title').html(title);        
        content.html($(this).html());
        $(".modal-profile").modal({show:true});
    });

  });
```